# Gravar na Base de Dados ao término de leilão

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Eu estou a desenvolver um site de leilões em ASP.NET MVC4 e EF, neste momento já efectua licitações e tem um cronômetro de tempo.

O problema agora é: como eu faço para gravar os dados quando o tempo termina? Já pensei em fazer um *trigger* na BD, mas penso que não irá resultar.

Penso que terei de ter no servidor IIS um *script* que detecta que o tempo terminou e grava os dados na BD, mas como faço isto?

Eu tenho o temporizador em JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#countdown').countdown({ until: '@timeSpan', format: 'DHMS' }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Não é melhor temporizar por JavaScript e enviar uma requisição Ajax?

Comment: Eu tenho o temporizador em JavaScript. <script type="text/javascript">                                  $('#countdown').countdown({ until: '@timeSpan', format: 'DHMS' });
 </script>

Answer (score 2):

Na documentação do jQuery Countdown, [há um parâmetro chamado `expiryUrl`](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#expiryUrl). Ele pode ser usado para fazer uma requisição Ajax para algum `Controller` seu.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#countdown').countdown({ 
        until: '@timeSpan', 
        format: 'DHMS',
        expiryUrl: '˜/MeuController/ActionAposExpirarTempo/?parametro=valor' 
    }); 
</script>
```

Aí é só criar a `Action` no `Controller`:

```
public JsonResult ActionAposExpirarTempo(String parametro) {
    // Faça alguma coisa aqui relacionada com a sua lógica

    return Json(new { status = "Ok"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

É só um exemplo. Ela não necessariamente precisa devolver um JSON.

Comment: Entendi a sua resposta, mas como faço que esse método seja executado quando o cronometro chegue a zero sem haver uma iteração do utilizador com os site?

Comment: Ele decresce sozinho, não?